Vite not found error during Heroku deployment
Background
So I've been trying to use Heroku to deploy an express server to staticly serve a React frontend SPA and also to host a set of RESTful APIs. The frontend is built with the vite build command into dist files before being served by the express server.
The repository to the code can be found here: https://github.com/ndrw1221/full-stack-personal-page
Issue
So the build process runs successfully locally, but when I try to deploy to Heroku (by git push heroku main), I encountered this error, saying that the vite package is not found:
...
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build (yarn)
remote:        yarn run v1.22.22
remote:        $ cd frontend && yarn build
remote:        $ vite build
remote: /bin/sh: 1: vite: not found
remote: error Command failed with exit code 127.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
remote: error Command failed with exit code 127.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
...

Failed Attempts
I've attempted the following solutions, but none of them resolve the issue:

Adjust Build Behavior: Configure Heroku to install devDenpendencies during the build process by runnning this command: heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false.

Moving Vite to Dependencies: Moving the vite package from devDependencies to dependencies.
frontend/package.json


{
  "name": "personal-page",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://ndrw1221.github.io/personal-page",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "yarn run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.18",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "gh-pages": "^6.1.1",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "match-sorter": "^6.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "sort-by": "^1.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "vite": "^5.2.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  }
}


Clear Build Cache on Heroku: Run heroku repo:purge_cache -a <my-app> followed by an empty commit and finally git push heroku main.

Remove node_modules from Source Control: As suggest in title.

Specify Node and Yarn Versions: Specify Node and Yarn versions in package.json.
package.json


"engines": {
    "node": "20.11.1",
    "yarn": "1.22.22"
  },

So despite all the attemps, I am not able to resolve the very issue mentioned above. I wonder if there are any compability issues or support issues between Heroku and Vite, or if there is something wrong with my code. Thank you.

I solved it now. It turns out that you have to yarn after cd into each directory. So the corrected version should look like this:
package.json
 "scripts": {
    "start": "cd backend && yarn && yarn start",
    "build": "cd frontend && yarn && yarn build"
  }

